# expect script failing on exec command

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I've got an expect script which seems to be failing... when I use puts to show me the contents of the command, it looks fine, but exec seems to be doing something funky which I've been struggling with for the past few minutes...
any ideas?

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f

    set recipients {
        "abc@abc.com"
        "xyz@abc.com"
    }
    set body "Success!"
    set subject "File Upload Status"
    set email_sender "EmailSender <Email.Sender@abc.com>"
    set smtp_server "smtp://webmail.abc.com"
    set recipient_list [join $recipients ","]
    set cmd "echo \"$body\" | mailx -s \"$subject\" -r \"$email_sender\" -S smtp=$smtp_server \"$recipient_list\""
    puts $cmd

    # Execute the mailx command
    exec $cmd
```

The failure occurs at the `exec` and the error I am seeing is this:

```
> ./test.expect
echo "Success!" | mailx -s "File Upload Status" -r "EmailSender <Email.Sender@abc.com>" -S smtp=smtp://webmail.abc.com "abc@abc.com,xyz@abc.com"
couldn't execute "echo "Success!" | mailx -s "File Upload Status" -r "EmailSender <Email.Sender@abc.com>" -S smtp=smtp:/webmail.abc.com "abc@abc.com,xyz@abc.com"": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec $cmd"
    (file "./test.expect" line 16)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried putting double quotes and single quotes around the `$cmd` in the last line but nothing has worked.

What I don't understand is why is the smtp server getting represented differently when getting executed but not when I run the puts command...

if I change the last line to

```
exec sh -c $cmd
```

everything works.
Why do I need to explicitly call `sh -c` and is there any way for me to avoid it?

Comment: You might be confused by some other (mostly older) languages using `system()` to invoke external commands by starting a shell with only a single string given as an argument, which the shell was then responsible for parsing out and executing. That's understood in modern times to be bad security practice; and even though TCL and expect are from back when it was commonly done, they managed to dodge the pitfall.

Comment: you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more familiar with shell syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcl`'s [`exec`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.html) can set up pipelines, but you have to have the separate commands separated by [`|` arguments](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.html#M8), not passing it all as a single string.

```
exec echo $body | mailx -s $subject -r $email_sender -S smtp=$smtp_server $recipient_list
```

But you actually don't need that here. [`<< value`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.html#M12) is like a shell herestring; it sets the standard input of the first command in a pipeline to the value; no need for `echo`.

Something like:

```
exec mailx -s $subject -r $email_sender -S smtp=$smtp_server $recipient_list << $body
```

should work. Note the lack of having to quote variables. `tcl` has saner expansion rules than most shells; they're not needed here.

You can also avoid having to join the list recipients into a single string; `mailx` can take individual email addresses as arguments, and [argument expansion (`{*}list`)](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.html#M9) will splice in the contents of the list as individual arguments:

```
exec mailx ... {*}$recipients << $body
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call `sh -c` because (a) you're not trying to execute a command; you're running a shell pipeline, and (b) even for a single command, `exec` requires an array, not a string argument. That is, these work:

```
expect1.1> exec date
Fri Jun 30 09:11:55 PM EDT 2023
expect1.2> exec echo "hello world"
hello world
```

But this will not:

```
expect1.1> exec "echo hello world"
couldn't execute "echo hello world": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec "echo hello world""
```

Because there is no command named `echo hello world`.

---

And of course, if you want to take advantage of shell-specific syntax like pipelines (`|`), i/o redirection (`<`, `>`, etc), and so forth, then you need to actually use the shell:

```
expect1.1> exec sh -c "echo hello world | sed s/world/people/"
hello people
```